# Swift class and PFObject

Tags: class, variables, swift

I have a Swift class with a PFObject as a var. In my code, I'm getting one PFObject (from a query to Parse.com) that I want to store in this var, but I get errors (depending on what I do at initialization time or not, I get a 'build failed' or an exception at runtime)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  var user: PFObject?

  func setUser() {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectId)
    var objects = query.findObjects()

    for object : PFObject! in objects {
        self.user = object as PFObject
    }
  }
}
```

With the above example, I get a Swift compiler error with this message:

```
Stored value type does not match pointer operand type!
 store %objc_object* %324, %CSo8PFObject** %34, align 8, !dbg !470
 %CSo8PFObject*LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
 Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

How should I do that?

Comment: What is the exact exception message? It is extremely difficult to know what is going on without this basic information. Also, where does `objects` come from in your code?

Comment: Anthony, edited above.

Answer (score 0):

If you Treat the User as an User instead of an object, You can follow this tutorial:
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS